# SwiftUI for MacOS Window with Rounded Corners without Title Bar

Tags: swiftui, nswindow, cornerradius

I'm wanting to achieve a corner radius on my NSWindow that has no title bar or miniaturizable set.  I've had to override NSWindow's canBecomeKey in order to make views in the window selectable.

I've seen lots of ways to achieve this for older versions of swift or those that use interface builder but I'm using swiftUI.

This is my NSWindow override:

```swift
class SWindow: NSWindow {
    override var canBecomeKey:Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

In App Delegate:

```swift
var searchWindow: SWindow!

let searchView = SearchView().cornerRadius(10)
searchWindow = SWindow(
    contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 850, height: 500),
    styleMask: [.resizable],
    backing: .buffered, defer: false)
searchWindow.center()
searchWindow.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
searchWindow.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
searchWindow.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
searchWindow.isOpaque = false
searchWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: searchView)
searchWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(true)
```

Adding the ***SearchView().cornerRadius(10)*** does seem to create a corner radius on the view but the window is still square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...create a corner radius on the view but the window is still square.

You need to remove window background

```
window.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
```

and, btw, add full content size

```
searchWindow = SWindow(
    contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 850, height: 500),
    styleMask: [.resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
    backing: .buffered, defer: false)
```

Comment: It works!   I had to set the background colour of the next child element but this works a treat.  Thanks for all your help today :)